# Fargate environment variable redis.yaml

Tags: aws-fargate, amazon-eks

I have a microservice and I need to pass in a file redis.yaml to configure Elasticache for Redis.

Assume I have a file called `redis.yaml` with contents:

```
clusterServersConfig:
  idleConnectionTimeout: 10000
  pingTimeout: 1000
  connectTimeout: 10000
  timeout: 60000
  retryAttempts: 3
  retryInterval: 60000
```

And my `application.properties` I use:

```
redis.config.location=file:/opt/usr/conf/redis.yaml
```

In Kubernetes, I can just create a secret with `--from-file redis.yaml` and the application runs properly.

I do not know how to do the same with AWS Fargate. I believe it could be done with AWS SSM but any help/steps on how to do it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For externalized configuration, Fargate supports environment variables. Environment variables can be passed in Task definition.

```
        "environment": [
            { "name": "env_name1", "value": "value1" },
            { "name": "env_name2", "value": "value2" }
        ]
```

If it's sensitive information, store it in AWS SSM-Parameter store (you can use KMS) and specify the parameter key in the task definition.

```
{
  "containerDefinitions": [{
    "secrets": [{
      "name": "environment_variable_name",
      "valueFrom": "arn:aws:ssm:region:aws_account_id:parameter/parameter_name"
    }]
  }]
}
```

In your case, you can convert your yaml to JSON and store it in the [Parameter store](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/systems-manager-parameter-store.html) and refer it in the task definition.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/specifying-sensitive-data.html

Comment: I am looking to add an encrypted file similar to Kubernetes `--from-file`. I shouldn't need to add 60 lines of environment variables. Instead, my app should just read that file with the variables.